# Why do multiple cards open simultaneously when clicking on a single card in my HTML/CSS/JavaScript setup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-handling, dom-manipulation

First off - rookie coder here, with little experience. I have a web page containing multiple cards, each representing a museum exhibit. Upon clicking on a card, I want only that specific card to expand and show additional information, while the others remain closed. However, I'm encountering an issue where clicking on one card opens both that card and another card simultaneously, while not displaying the text on the inactive one.

HTML:

```
<div id="museum-container">
  <!-- Museum 1: Harmony Through Time -->
  <div class="museum-card" onclick="toggleMuseum(this)">
    <img src="music_museum.jpg" alt="Harmony Through Time" class="museum-image">
    <div class="museum-name">harmony through time</div>
    <div class="museum-description">Explore the evolution of music through the ages.</div>
    <button class="start-button" onclick="startMuseum('harmony through time')">Start</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Museum 2: Time Capsule -->
  <div class="museum-card" onclick="toggleMuseum(this)">
    <img src="time_capsule.jpg" alt="time capsule" class="museum-image">
    <div class="museum-name">time capsule</div>
    <div class="museum-description">Embark on a journey through historical artifacts and moments.</div>
    <button class="start-button" onclick="startMuseum('time capsule')">Start</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggleMuseum(card) {
    var isActive = card.classList.contains('active');
  
    // Remove active class from all cards
    document.querySelectorAll('.museum-card').forEach(function (element) {
      element.classList.remove('active');
    });
  
    // Toggle active class only on the clicked card
    if (!isActive) {
      card.classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.museum-card.active .museum-description,
.museum-card.active .start-button {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background-color:rgb(177, 134, 70);
}
```

I've tried using an alert function to find where the error is, but no matter where I put it, it wouldn't even appear.

Comment: The default display of elements is `block`, or `inline`, or `inline-block` etc - there's nothing in your CSS to hide anything, so why would it be hidden? - try using `.museum-card:not(.active)` (both times) and `display:none;`

Comment: Just re-read the question, and what you describe does NOT happen

Comment: Not exactly related, but if you're going to hide inactive cards, you can't reopen the cards again, as you can't click on a hidden element.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this, you can stop event propagation using event.stopPropagation() in your toggleMuseum function. Here's how you can modify your JavaScript code:

function toggleMuseum(card, event) {
event.stopPropagation(); // Stop event propagation

```
var isActive = card.classList.contains('active');

// Remove active class from all cards
document.querySelectorAll('.museum-card').forEach(function (element) {
    element.classList.remove('active');
});

// Toggle active class only on the clicked card
if (!isActive) {
    card.classList.add('active');
}
```

}

Comment: And update your HTML to pass the event to the toggleMuseum function


<div class="museum-card" onclick="toggleMuseum(this, event)">